# Select records from one table based on records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is a simplified version of a problem I'm having,

I have two tables:

```
Table1 has two columns (Stuff, YesNo) and 
Table2 has one column (Stuff)
```

The records in the YesNo Column will either be 1 or 0

How could I select records in Table2 where the records in Table1.YesNo = 1

Many Thanks

Comment: Start by reading about joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  Second Identify how the tables relate.  Is the STUFF column in table1 the same as stuff in table2?  Do the tables have a primary/foreign key relationship?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Table2.*
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Stuff = Table2.Stuff
WHERE Table1.YesNo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this would be your solution:

```
Select Stuff From Table2
Where Exists (
    Select 'Y'
    From   Table1
    Where  Table1.Stuff = Table2.Stuff
    And    YesNo = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I believe you'll need data from both tables and you may want to render fields unique to each table This seems like a likely response.  However, as I don't believe STUFF accurately represents the relationship... you'll need to quantify/adjust the `on a.stuff = b.stuff` so that the join includes all necessary fields.

```
SELECT A.Stuff, B.Stuff, B.YesNo
FROM table1 B
INNER JOIN table2 A
   on A.Stuff = B.Stuff
WHERE B.YesNo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM TABLE1 T1
            JOIN TABLE2 T2
                ON T1.Stuff = T2.Stuff
WHERE   T1.YesNo = 1
```